# The best unitary matrices that approximate a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an arbitrary $N\times N$ complex matrix. Moreover, $\mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{U}_2$ are distinct subsets of all unitary matrices. Suppose the matrices $\mathbf{U}_1$ and $\mathbf{V}_1$ are selected from $\mathcal{U}_1$. What is the solution of the following optimization problem
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{U}_2,\mathbf{V}_2\in\mathcal{U}_2} \|\mathbf{U}_2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{V}_2-\mathbf{U}_1\mathbf{A}\mathbf{V}_1\|_F
\end{align}
Can we say that the optimal $\mathbf{U}_2$ and $\mathbf{V}_2$ are the solution of the following \begin{align}
\mathbf{U}_2^\ast&=\text{arg}\min_{\mathbf{U}_2\in\mathcal{U}_2} \|\mathbf{U}_2-\mathbf{U}_1\|_F\\
\mathbf{V}_2^\ast&=\text{arg}\min_{\mathbf{V}_2\in\mathcal{U}_2} \|\mathbf{V}_2-\mathbf{V}_1\|_F
\end{align}

Comment: Have you checked the quantum compilation literature?

Comment: Yes. I have checked it.